# paging problem with a 2\columnwith image on a three-column text

Tags: graphics

i'm having an paging problem including a two-column large image inside a three-column text page.
I tried with the code:

```
  \documentclass[]{book}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{{./Immagini/}}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \addtolength{\columnsep}{1.5mm}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
    \blindtext[2]
    \makebox[2\columnwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=2\columnwidth, keepaspectratio]{rect3050}}
    \blindtext[2]
    \end{multicols}
    \end{document}
```

Of corse the result is not what I want:

[image]

Of course I could choose the text to put in the third column using a code like:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./Immagini/}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm}%     margini
\usepackage{multicol}
\addtolength{\columnsep}{1.5mm}%     spazio tra le colonne
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\blindtext
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\makebox[2\columnwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=2\columnwidth, keepaspectratio]{rect3050.png}}
\phantom{a}
\columnbreak
\phantom{a}\\\phantom{a}
\columnbreak

\blindtext
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\blindtext
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

But the result is still not what I want because the text is not continuous in the three sections that are created.

[image]

I also tried with the ambient 'floatfigure' but with no satisfying result because the package is thought for figures smaller than the width of the text in which they appear.

---

The result that i'd like to obtain is something like this:
[image]
Is unnecessary to specify that I want the text to be continuous 1,2,3,4,5...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect way to post. I'm new in the forum.

I changed my post improving the code and changing images (because of copyright).

Hope somebody can help me soon!..:)